# Canvas Paint text size android

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have a mutable Bitmap and I'm drawing it on a Canvas. After that I want to draw a pre-defined text on the bitmap. The problem is I have different bitmap sizes, even though I'm setting the text size to 20sp, depending on the bitmap size the text is bigger of smaller, but I want the text size to be the same for ALL images. What Should I do? I thought of maybe scaling the text size depending on the image width and weight but I'm not sure how to do that.

```
final Bitmap mutableBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
final Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setTextSize(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.myFontSize);
canvas.drawText(text, x, y, paint);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of if this is your onDraw method you are doing wrong work here. You shouldn't allocate anything inside the onDraw method. On the other hand , you shouldn't change your text size for bitmaps. Resize your bitmaps on same values(width and height) , then setting the text for same value.